# Check if record already exists when doing a buffer-copy

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I have a piece of code which does a Buffer-Copy method, but is there any way to check before doing the buffer copy of the record already exists? **I do not want to check 'unique keys' in my data dictionary.**

This is the code I have at this moment:

```
    CREATE QUERY hQuery.
    hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(hBuffer).
    hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("FOR EACH " + hBuffer:NAME + " NO-LOCK ").  
    hQuery:QUERY-OPEN().


    hQuery:GET-FIRST().
    DO WHILE NOT hQuery:QUERY-OFF-END:
        DO TRANSACTION ON ERROR UNDO:

            hDBBuffer:BUFFER-CREATE().
            hDBBuffer:BUFFER-COPY(hBuffer) NO-ERROR.
```

Comment: Presumably you are copying from one table to another? Why do you not want to check unique keys? Are you wanting to test for duplication of every field in the buffer?

Comment: If you are not checking unique keys what is your criteria for "already exists"?

Comment: Sorry I guess I explained it wrong, when making the table in the data dictionary you can click the checkbox to enable unique keys on indexes. I do not want to do this in my data dictionary but I want to check it programmatically.

Comment: FWIW I  think that "checking it programmatically" has nothing to do with using BUFFER-COPY and that you would be better off formulating a stand alone question on how to programmatically ensure uniqueness in the absence of defined unique keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish and why you don't want to check unique keys "in my data dictionary" or even what you mean by that.

Your example code is very sketchy and incomplete, maybe someone else can figure out what you are trying to do and why, but I am at a loss to divine the purpose behind it.  The use of handles and dynamic queries is especially puzzling.  There doesn't seem to be a reason for that or any need to do that.

None the less, if I were coding a routine to copy a buffer, couldn't look up unique indexes in the dictionary, and wanted to pro-actively avoid potential collisions I might write something like this:

```
define temp-table oLine like orderLine.

for each orderline no-lock:
  find oLine of orderLine no-error.
  if not available( oLine ) then create oLine.
  buffer-copy orderLine to oline.
end.
```

(Using static coding to keep the example simple.)

(I wouldn't really use **OF** - it is on my personal forbidden list, I think it is terrible from a documentation and maintenance perspective.)

Comment: What I am trying to do is delete a record and then re-add it to the database. When I re-add it i have a Dataset containing the new data. But now when I have data in the dataset with the same indexes let's say a CustNum it writes it two times because the 'Unique keys' checkbox wasn't checked in the DataDictionary for that specific Table.

Comment: My advice to you is that you should make the key unique.  You are only delaying the inevitable by attempting to code around it.  You will end up with a buggy unmaintainable mess trying to programmatically enforce uniqueness in this way.

Comment: I've edited my response - rather than skip or DELETE a duplicate record just over-write it.  (But you still have the problem of how do you know a record is a duplicate without a reliable unique key...)

Answer (score 1):

I believe, as Tom has mentioned in his reply, it'd be most appropriate to have another dynamic query directed at the hDBBuffer using the BUFFER-FIELDs and BUFFER-VALUEs from hBuffer and check the NUM-RESULTS after you use QUERY-OPEN. Then delete the query for memory purposes. 
But yes, you would be looking for the metadata unique keys to achieve that. I understand you don't want to do it, but it's REALLY the best way, can't stress it enough.

Now if you would really like to check for the existence of ALL the record data, look into the BUFFER-COMPARE method. You could create a second dynamic query, then cycle all records there by using buffer-compare to match the entire record you're looking at to the one you're assessing whether to create, or list the ones you wish to include or exclude. This approach is way less performatic, though, please keep that in mind.